# powerbase.h file is missing in the mingw include folder

Tags: c, windows, winapi, compiler-errors, mingw

I am not able to include powerbase.h file in the c application, because this file is not available under the `mingw` include path - "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include". However, the powerbase.h file is present in the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um" path. I want to detect the windows resume events in the c application, I believe I need to include `powerbase.h` file to register for the windows resume events. Do you know why mingw include folder does not have powerbase.h file?

I was using `mingw 8.1.0` version. I upgraded it to `mingw 11.2.0` version. Still I get the same issue.

Comment: It isn't a standard library so why would Mingw include it? You might want to consider copying that lib to your local project path instead.

Comment: Thats a fact: MinGW "Windows" headers are not official, there's a lot of headers missing, other not up to date, etc. The Windows SDK is the only official source for the Windows API. You can write a missing header and participate to MinGW.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will add the header file in my c application

Comment: You "believe" you need to include `powerbase.h`? I recommend checking which functions you need and include what is needed to use them.

Comment: Thanks @BrechtSanders I will check the header file.